# Which laws of physics does this problem break?

Tags: thermodynamics, laws-of-physics

[One of the problems](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/8234486/dashboard#s=p1) from the Google Code Jam programming competition, round 2 2015, goes like this:

> A kiddie pool is a big container in which you can put water, so that
>   small children can play in it.
>
> You have access to **N** different sources of water. The
>   i<sup>th</sup> source of water produces water at rate
>   **R**<sub>i</sub> and at temperature **C**<sub>i</sub>. Initially, all of the water sources are off. Each source of water can be switched on
>   only once, and switched off only once; *the act of switching a source
>   on or off takes no additional time*. Multiple sources can be on at the
>   same time.
>
> *Your pool can hold an infinite amount of water*, but you want to fill the pool to a volume of exactly **V** with a temperature of exactly
>   **X**, as quickly as possible. If you turn sources on and off optimally (not every source necessarily has to be used), what's the
>   minimum number of seconds it will take you to do this?
>
> For the purposes of this problem, *combining water that has volume
>   **V**<sub>0</sub> and temperature **X**<sub>0</sub> with water that has volume **V**<sub>1</sub> and temperature **X**<sub>1</sub> will
>   **instantaneously** create water with volume **V**<sub>0</sub>+**V**<sub>1</sub> and temperature (**V**<sub>0</sub>**X**<sub>0</sub> +
>   **V**<sub>1</sub>**X**<sub>1</sub>) / (**V**<sub>0</sub> + **V**<sub>1</sub>)*. For example, combining 5L of water at 10 degrees with 10L of water at 40 degrees will result in 15L of water at 30
>   degrees. You should also assume that *water does not heat or cool over
>   time except as a result of being combined with other water*.
>
> [input and output specification not included]

I emphasized (in italics) some statements that are useful simplifications for the problem, but don't seem to agree with reality. Could you explain which laws of physics are broken here?

Comment: You cannot mix water in no time. You will at least have to stir well to equate the temperatures, which takes additional time.

Answer (score 2):

**Reality:**

Arguably, no rules of Physics are broken.
You can take the perspective that the results of actions are within the accuracy achievable by measurement and/or requirement and that actions which are stated to be instantaneous are carried out in such a way that they have the effect of having occurred at a fixed point in time.

For example, with careful design flow could be stopped or started within 0.1 second with relative ease and say 0.01 second "with only some additional engineering". If you wanted flow to last 10.00 seconds and the characteristic of the valve were well known then you could achieve a mean period at full flow within say 0.1 to 0.01 seconds. 0.1s = 1% and 0.01s = 0.1%. A number of ~= 1% errors will affect the outcome noticeably if all have the same sign and are thus cumulative, but if these are randomly distributed above and below the target value the mean result becomes MORE accurate with increasing stages.

**Pedants day out:**

However, if one wished to be pedantic, one could argue:

> The ith source of water produces water at **rate** Ri ....
>   and at **temperature** Ci ...
>   fill the pool to a volume of exactly V ...

None of rate or temperature or volume can be precise - initially due to control, metering and measurement errors and, for the ultra pedants, due to Hesienbergs uncertainty principal

So too for other uses of these variables.

> switching ... takes no additional time.

This implies exact time period measurement, again impossible,

> combining 5L of water at 10 degrees with 10L of water at 40 degrees will result in 15L of water at 30 degrees.

This assumes specific heat of water (in this case) is constant with temperature, which it isn't. Mixing different volumes at different temperatures will produce a mixture which **extremely slightly,** deviates in temperature from what simplistic calculation assumes.

Mixing perfectly takes nearlyt infinite time - with theoretical infinite time being prevented by a finite number of distinct 'particles' (molecules, Avagadros law).
If the flyid enters with non-zero velocity the kinetic energy in the flow will be converted to heat and in an open system sone water vapour will leave.

> water does not heat or cool over time except as a result of being combined with other water.

Bzzzt. Perfect insulation not available.

BUT - while the pedants are having a field day the engineers can implement this in the 0.1% - 1% range without too much bother, and much much better if needs must.

Comment: Watch out, "engineer" is a dirty word 'round here :)

Comment: @user3823992 Yes, indeed. I'm aware that some people suffer from an unfortunate disconnect from reality and an inability (or refusal (or both)) to apply the fruits of their labours to reaping the rewards they convey. Such is life.

Comment: @user3823992 I'm sure there was meant to be a :-) on the end of my response :-)